# Modeling curvy things with blender

Tags: modeling

I am having a problem with modeling objects that have curves like ps4 controller, cars, etc. 
is there an easy way to do that.

Comment: This is usually done with *[subdivision surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdivision_surface)* modeling or with [NURBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_rational_B-spline) (though Blender's NURBS capabilities are fairly limited).

Comment: Do you have any examples of that ? And thank you

Answer (score 2):

The main way of modeling curved things is to use [Subdivision Surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdivision_surface) modeling.  The idea of subsurf modeling is to model the basic blocky shape, then apply a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to the mesh.  Subsurf works by [recursively subdividing and smoothing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mX0NB9IyYpU) the mesh.  To make sharper corners you can add *proximity cuts*.  Proximity cuts are loop cuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) which are made close to corners in the mesh to tighten up the smoothing at that corner.

[image]

Here is a very simple example of a game controller like object which I have modeled.  You can see the base mesh is the black wireframe cage and the grey solid mesh is after subsurf.  Proximity cuts are highlighted in orange.

Answer (score 0):

It is usualy done with subdivision modeling as @PGMath has suggested. You would start with the rough shape, and boundaries, and then connect all the vertices and apply the subdivision modifier.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4id4p2Kwyd4) is a youtube screen capture of someone modelling a ps4 controller with Blender. And [here](http://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/3dsmax-sony-ps4-controller/725853) are some reference clay models for final topology on turbosquid.

Comment: The YouTube link you sent dose not work unfortunately can you send another one for anything that has many curves